# Display Notifications on Tabs

Tags: android, notifications

I am working in an android project, I need to display the notification `on the tab` when a new message arrives. How can we add this notification please help me............. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use Broadcast Receiver for checking incoming message and  on Receive of the Broadcast check for ndroid.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED

```
if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {} like this
```

and use NotificationManager to show notification

```
mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                    Notification notifyDetails = new Notification(R.drawable.icon,"message received",System.currentTimeMillis());
```